# how to remove black space on my wordpress 2016

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having problems reducing and/or removing the black space at the bottom of my wordpress webpage. Using inspector the black space seems to go over 2 css divs.

I need to add code in the custom css area to solve this but I dont know what to add.

```
 http://andrewt.com.au/wp1/

  this is the footer.php code 
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
?>

        </div><!-- .site-content -->

        <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
            <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
                <nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer Primary Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location' => 'primary',
                            'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
                         ) );
                    ?>
                </nav><!-- .main-navigation -->
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>
                <nav class="social-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer Social Links Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location' => 'social',
                            'menu_class'     => 'social-links-menu',
                            'depth'          => 1,
                            'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
                            'link_after'     => '</span>',
                        ) );
                    ?>
                </nav><!-- .social-navigation -->
            <?php endif; ?>

        </footer><!-- .site-footer -->
    </div><!-- .site-inner -->
</div><!-- .site -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: what other information is required?

Comment: As I mentioned in my other comment, a [mcve]. You posted PHP which isn't relevant here. Post the bare minimum HTML and CSS that recreates the issue.

Comment: something is wrong with the url you provided. Its seems to be server side error. Check it ` http://andrewt.com.au/wp1/` and fix the issue. or create new question with new information and issues

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your footer.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
?>
<style>
    @media screen and (min-width: 61.5625em){
        .content-area .site-main {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
    }
</style>
    </div><!-- .site-content -->

    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
            <nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer Primary Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>">
                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                        'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
                     ) );
                ?>
            </nav><!-- .main-navigation -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>
            <nav class="social-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer Social Links Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>">
                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'theme_location' => 'social',
                        'menu_class'     => 'social-links-menu',
                        'depth'          => 1,
                        'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
                        'link_after'     => '</span>',
                    ) );
                ?>
            </nav><!-- .social-navigation -->
        <?php endif; ?>

    </footer><!-- .site-footer -->
</div><!-- .site-inner -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Your website is broken, or have very-very-very bad coded.

Add this css rules to custom css area( as you mentioned ):

```
#main{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
footer{
   padding: 5px; //or you can decrease/increase it
}
```

If after adding and refreshing/deleting cache of page, it doesn't affected, than try to use:

```
#main{
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
footer{
   padding: 5px !important; //or you can decrease/increase it
}
```

or try to write the rules provided to some other stylesheet, such as default customizer of wordpress: `Customize => Additional Css`.